# Apparently Breeze not supported for MVC5 webapi on VS2013 Preview

Tags: breeze, hottowel, visual-studio-2013

Just a request to get a Breeze version that support MVC5 and razor v3.

This is what I did:
1. Create a default WebAPI project from VS2013 Preview (with ASP.NET web tools refresh update)
2. Add package for hottowel
3. Compile and run

Get:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

[A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\xinqiu\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3abbc5e1\49de5a8a\assembly\dl3\c1b6d75e\22a35840_4778ce01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\xinqiu\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3abbc5e1\49de5a8a\assembly\dl3\c1b6d75e\22a35840_4778ce01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.

Source Error: 


An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidCastException: [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\xinqiu\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3abbc5e1\49de5a8a\assembly\dl3\c1b6d75e\22a35840_4778ce01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.]
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.GetRazorSection(String virtualPath) +151
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath, String physicalPath) +209
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath) +46
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.GetHostFromConfig() +58
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.CreateHost() +62
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_Host() +65
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode() +83
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() +54
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) +59
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +209
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +15
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +9949713
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +299
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +165
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath) +10
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath) +28
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath) +47
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +175
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +480
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +50
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +123
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +582
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +115
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +321
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +140
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +63
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +45
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +81
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +146
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +66
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +146
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +66
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +45
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +81
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +146
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +66
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +49
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9631512
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.32559
```

I believe this is due to Breeze controller compiled with MVC4 and thus meet this conflict.  Can we have a version of Breeze that supports MVC5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Breeze has nothing to do with MVC. No part of Breeze has any dependence on any version of MVC. If you're getting an MVC error, it can't be caused by Breeze. I don't see anything in the stack trace to suggest otherwise.

There may be something incompatible in HotTowel ... or one of the MVC templates.

Comment: I'll mark this as answer and keep looking of what's wrong.  Some package was compiled using webpage v2 and caused the incompatiblility, I thought it's breeze since it has a server side component.  But I guess it might be something else then.  I'll keep checking.

Comment: Turns out it's hottowel is for MVC4 right now.  For MVC5, one needs to change ~/Views/Web.config to something like following:

Comment: too long to post, basically, needs to update web.config assembly version from 2.0 -> 3.0 for system.web.webPages.razor section group, and 4.0->5.0 for host factory and page controls and attributes